# Kerberized Hadoop Login failure for user ... LoginException: Checksum failed

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

### Environment:

- Hadoop 2.9.2
- Kerberos 5 release 1.15.1
- RHEL 7

### Error

Exception in Hadoop datanode log that prevents startup.

The log entry is:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: Login failure for user: datanode/_HOST@<REALM> from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/<file.keytab> javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Checksum failed
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: Login failure for user: datanode/_HOST@<REALM> from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/datanode.keytab javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Checksum failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:1104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:312)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2596)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.SecureDataNodeStarter.start(SecureDataNodeStarter.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Checksum failed
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:808)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:618)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:1095)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: KrbException: Checksum failed
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:102)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:94)
        at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(EncryptedData.java:175)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.decrypt(KrbAsRep.java:150)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.decryptUsingKeyTab(KrbAsRep.java:121)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.resolve(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:308)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:447)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:780)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decryptCTS(AesDkCrypto.java:451)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decrypt(AesDkCrypto.java:272)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256.decrypt(Aes256.java:76)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:100)
        ... 30 more
```

### Diagnose

If **kdiag** is run to diagnose the problem:

```
bin/hadoop org.apache.hadoop.security.KDiag --principal namenode/_HOST@<REALM> --keytab /etc/security/keytab/namenode.keytab
```

The same exception as above is encountered...

The last line of useful output is:

```
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
```

Normal healthy output should be:

```
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.HmacSha1Aes256CksumType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply datanode/_HOST
```

### /etc/krb5.conf

Contents of Kerberos Configuration

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  dns_lookup_kdc = false
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
  renew_lifetime = 7d
  rdns = false
  forwardable = true
  # pkinit_anchors = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
  default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
  EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = kdc.example.com
  admin_server = kdc.example.com
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
}
[domain_realm]
.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: For the record: Java has its own (crude) implementation of Kerberos, and Hadoop libraries override part of that implementation with custom code. So the version of the Kerberos lib shipped with the OS does not really matter; it's the version of Java (and the vendor - Oracle, OpenJDK, IBM etc) that matters.

Comment: Especially since older versions of Java **never** created renewable tickets.That's the way it worked with Java 7 and Java 8 anyway. Looks like Java 9+ work differently -- and breaks some assumptions in Hadoop libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hadoop documentation explains this is a problem with Java not supporting renewable tickets.

> **1.8.0_242** Kerberos Java client will fail by "Message stream modified (41)" when the client requests a renewable ticket and the KDC
> returns a non-renewable ticket. If your principal is not allowed to
> obtain a renewable ticket, you must remove "renew_lifetime" setting
> from your krb5.conf.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions

## Option 1

Remove `renew_lifetime` from `krb5.conf`

*Note:* If you don't want to disable renewable kerberos tickets system-wide you can configure a custom `krb5.conf` for `java` by passing these arguments to the jvm:

```
# non-windows
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf
# windows
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.ini
```

According to [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-yarn-dev/201909.mbox/%3CCAKRKJ1O3yrYKDZ=WhU=i6A+zqxFnUidxvwQzNCTW0mnEv2WFPA@mail.gmail.com%3E)

## Option 2

Ensure `renew_lifetime`, `ticket_lifetime` and `max_renewable_life` are set.

Example working config

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
  dns_lookup_kdc = false
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
  renew_lifetime = 7d
  forwardable = true
  default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-hmac-sha1 arcfour-hmac des-hmac-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des- cbc-crc
  default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-hmac-sha1 arcfour-hmac des-hmac-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
  permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-hmac-sha1 arcfour-hmac des-hmac-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
  kdc_timeout = 3000

[realms]
  EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = kdc.example.com
  admin_server = kdc.example.com
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
  }

[domain_realm]
.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```